# How do I get a decent work environment in my OS X terminal and the IRB? And how is yours?

Tags: macos, terminal.app

How do I get a decent work environment in my OS X terminal and the IRB? And how is yours?

For example: in the screenshot below, mine is on the left and something I would prefer is on the right.

([View full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh2Bt.png))

[image]

How can I get those colors and font weights?

Comment: This question should be a CW; _a decent work envinronment_ is pretty subjective and there is not a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can colorize your IRB using [Wirble](http://pablotron.org/software/wirble/), I think that's what you're seeing in that screenshot. A good place to look is to search for "dotfiles" on Github and see what kind of tricks other people put in their `.irbrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal gives you presets in Preferences (⌘ + ,). Under "Settings" you should see a default set of presets but you can add more or edit the previous ones. This should be carried onto IRB as well, I'm using Grass. Is this what you're asking for?